# Can I have a ruby block inside another ruby block?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash whose keys are a range of integers (lets say `[1..5]`) and its corresponding 5 values are all `nil`. I have also an array of integers (lets say `[1,2,3,4,5]`. What I want to do is very specific: I want to take every single key and add it to every single of the array elements, giving me a hash that has the original keys, but has now for values the entire shifted array.

After spending a few hours I have concluded that this is impossible through a really laconic expression, because it is leading to .each shadowing statements.

I think that the only way to go through with this is to create 5 almost identical methods and call them separately.

```
def a1 
  array.each do |x|
    x+1
  end
end

def a2
  array.each do |x|
    x+2
  end
end
```

and so on..

The end product I want to achieve is this:

```
{1=>[2,3,4,5,6],2=>[3,4,5,6,7],3=>[4,5,6,7,8],4=>[5,6,7,8,9],5=>[6,7,8,9,10]}
```

It feels like there should be a more DRY way to achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these initial conditions:

```
h = {1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil, 5=>nil}
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

...it's pretty straightforward:

```
h.keys.each do |key|
  h[key] = arr.map {|i| i+key}
end
# h is now: {1=>[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2=>[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3=>[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4=>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5=>[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

(However, it may be that your question is about *achieving* the initial conditions. If so, I didn't grasp that, and I didn't worry about it; I just started with what I took to *be* your initial conditions and ended up with your desired result.)

Comment: Hey that works! But can you really have a block inside another block? I ve started writing this yesterday before posting on stack, but I ve got a text editor warning about shadowing statements and got me spooked. To be honest I am kinda surprised to the downvote.. I ve seen much more beginner questions on stack overflow.. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Hey I didnt know this as well!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this

```
h = {}
rng.each{|i| h[i] = ary.map{|j| j + i}}
```

That should work where `rng` is the range and `ary` is the array.

For example

```
h = {}
(1..5).each{|i| h[i] = [1,2,3,4,5].map{|j| j+i}}
```

results in

```
h = {1=>[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2=>[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3=>[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 4=>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5=>[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

Comment: Good answer but the hashes I gave in the example are just an example! Their structure is the way it is just for the sake of simplicity. Thanks a lot anyway.